# Error while displaying photo on my datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview, heidisql

I can't display photo from heidiSQL in my datagridview. There is an error and I don't know how to cope with it because my source code is exactly the same as a person that I'm study with. Only difference is that he is using phpmyadmin.

```cs
Student student = new Student();
private void StudentsList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // populate the datagridview with students data

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `students`");
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    DataGridViewImageColumn picCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 80;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = student.getStudents(command);
    picCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[7];
    picCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kilx0.png
Error I get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533845/system-argumentexception-parameter-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed the problem. I needed to add .ToArray() to my picture variable when I was converting it into parameter.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
String editQuery = "sql query";
command.CommandText = editQuery;
command.Connection = conn.getConnection();

command.Parameters.Add("@pic", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = picture.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I would use a column `Name` instead of an `Index`; it's where it can get mixed easily. I believe it should be:

```
picCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["ImageDBColumnName"];
```

This applies also to your `DataSource`, `SELECT *` is a bad practice. You should list your data columns and also refer by their names.

Then, what is the file `type` of your images? You didn't mention that.

But I would focus also on the **order of definitions**. You set the properties quite randomly, I would suggest fist to define `DataGridView` properties such as `Columns` (most importantly ensure that intended image column is of type `DataGridViewImageColumn`) and only at the last moment, set the `DataGridView.DataSource`. Specifically here I see a potential problem:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = student.getStudents(command);
picCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[7];
```

I personally prefer to use GUI to set up `DataGridView` columns, as it offloads a lot of code from the solution and you can be sure, they are set before your code is executed. However, if your datasource happens to be empty, you will loose those definitions. An easy solution is to use `DataTable` as data mediator.